# match fill gradient across different plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

lets say I have this data:

```
d1 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:3], y=LETTERS[24:26], num = 1:3)
d2 <- data.frame(x = letters[1:3], y=LETTERS[24:26], num = c(1,2,30))

library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2) 

ggd1 <- ggplot(d1, aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
          geom_tile(aes(fill=num)) + 
          scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "blue")
ggd2 <- ggplot(d2, aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
          geom_tile(aes(fill=num)) + 
          scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "blue")

grid.arrange(ggd1,ggd2)
```

[image]

My question is how can I standardise the fill gradient so that even though the extent of the data in d1 and d2 differ, colours for `X-a`,`Y-b` shoud match for both plots but `Z-c` should differ by an order of magnitude. i.e. I want to keep the same scale for both plots.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add limits to each plot:

```
ggd1 <- ggplot(d1, aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=num)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "blue", limits=c(1, 30))
ggd2 <- ggplot(d2, aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill=num)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "blue", limits=c(1, 30))
grid.arrange(ggd1,ggd2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you wish the scale of the plots to be the same, it may suffice with one scale. Then, instead of using `grid.arrange`, you may bind the two data sets together, and add a grouping variable which can be used in `facet_wrap`:

```
d3 <- rbind(d1, d2)
d3$grp <- rep(1:2, each = 3)

# You may also create a group variable before binding the df:s together, e.g.
d1$grp <- 1
d2$grp <- 2
rbind(d1, d2)



ggplot(d3, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = num)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "green", high = "blue") +
  facet_wrap(~ grp, ncol = 1)
```

[image]